# AIR HTML control having non local location does not run as application sandbox

Tags: security, air

I have HTML control on my main window like so:

```
<mx:HTML 
    id="hidHTML"
    location="http://localhost/index.html"
    enabled="true"
    paddingLeft="0"
    paddingRight="0"
    width="100%" height="100%"/>
```

The content of index.html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        window.runtime.trace("wrong sandbox");
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    "remote" file
</body>
</html>
```

Opening the app gets me:

```
TypeError: Result of expression 'window.runtime' [undefined] is not an object.
```

Changing location to "index.html" and having index.html in my application directory (same content in index.html) gets me:

```
wrong sandbox
```

Obviously AIR has changed sandbox security when location is set to something other than the app dir. Funny enough I can't find anything in the manual about it:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/HTML.html#location

Nor can I find anything that actually works to set the sandbox security back to application, any property or method of the mx:HTML that is.

Does anyone know how I can get application security for mx:HTML or find the documentation on why it's not running in application and the reason behind this?

Comment: You can call this line window.runtime.trace("wrong sandbox"); after triggered onload event but i'm not sure.

Comment: Hello Raja, thank you for looking into this. It's not that it's available at a later time (after onload). Having index.html in the application directory (same content) traces the message without a problem. It's that http://localhost is considored "unsafe" for some reason and window.runtime (only available in the appliction sandbox) isn't available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you find every security knowladge:

[HTML security in Adobe AIR](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7f11.html)

Comment: Thank you Viktor, I have seen that page and it seems to not mention mx.control.HTML at all,  nor does the page http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/HTML.html.mention anything about how to set sandbox for the HTML comtrol when setting location property

Comment: My guess that anything not in the application directory is not save and there is no way to change that.